# how to use value in cell to count up to a number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help with a formula.
I have a spreadsheet where the user enters an integer in one cell. i need to use that value to place a formula in another cell.
so, for example, user enters 24 in the cell. I need it to place a simple sum formula in the 24th cell of the row immediately to the left and highlight it red.
is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you have a column with formulas? You can use Conditional Formatting to check if the cell is blank, and for your formula you can do like `=If(and($A$1<>"",row()=$A$1),[sum formula],"")` assuming the user enters data in `A1`.  Put that formula in whatever column, and drag down.

Comment: @BruceWayne you really do not need the `$A$1<>""` part, if it is blank it will never equal a row number and therefor will fill the whole column with `""`.

Comment: Do you need the sum() to be on row 24 or do you want to sum(A1:A24)? Placing the sum on row 24 means the column needs to hold a formula, not impossible but it will render the column useless. However suming A1:A24 to say B1 is doable and will probably meet your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

You would put the SUM formula in an IF() function that is true when the row = the value in the cell:

```
=IF(ROW()=$E$2,$E$3-SUM($B$1:$B1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. can you clarify some? Basically i have the user calculate payment amounts. so you put the balance in P3 and the number of payments in P3. if P3 is 24, i need P28 to have the formula as such:
=P3-SUM()
with the sum being cells P4:P27 but I need it to be dynamic based on the value in number of payments. i hope that makes sense

Comment: Nope,  Try putting some test data and expected outcome in the original post. @user3712400

Comment: @user3712400 See edit, you may need to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

[OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) may be a great option here.

If I understand what you are saying, based on your comment to @ScottCraner's answer, you can use this formula in say P4 or wherever really.

`=P3-SUM(OFFSET(P4,0,0,P3,1)`

This will work if you do not **need** the formula to be exactly in the cell P28 or wherever it's defined, but just want to SUM the number of payments based on the trigger in `P3`.